# Complete chat solution in NodeJs

Tags: node.js

I don't know if it is the right place to answer this, but is there any cometchat-like solution for Node ?

(But perhaps I should migrate the question to meta?)

Comment: meta is for "bugs, features, and discussion of Stack Overflow and the Stack Exchange Q&A engine" so probably not meta.

Comment: so perhaps it is the right place :)

Comment: Award wining question @josh Crozier

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google is your friend for find excellent examples:
[node.js chat socket.io example](https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js%20chat%20socket.io%20example)

One great chat example can be found at:

http://psitsmike.com/2011/09/node-js-and-socket-io-chat-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Socket.io ships with a chat demo, which is essentially what the Drupal module I blogged about building is based on.

I basically took the socket.io chat demo and reworked it as a Drupal module that uses the Drupal user name as chat user name, and displays the chat interface on a page of a Drupal site.

Thanks for the link, Robert. ;)

Answer (score 0):

No there doesn't seem to be a complete out of the box chat solution. There are lots of examples of building a chat service using socket.io. Socket.io is a lot of fun don't be afraid to give it a go.

Here is blog post on building a chat module:
http://willvincent.com/blog/building-custom-realtime-chat-module-drupal-7-part-1